# How can I upload to Google Music via a proxy?

Tags: proxy, google-musicmanager

I installed the Google Music Manager and it works fine without a proxy. However I have a proxy set in ubuntu and it is unable to connect to upload. However, it is able to log in just fine.

Has anyone managed to upload music to Google using the Music Manager on Ubuntu via a proxy?

I have already tried various combinations of the environment variables `http_proxy`, `ALL_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the most reliable solution for this conundrum so far. Its to use a VPN. I recently subscribed to one and it doesn't require me to go through the proxy anymore. That covers my needs.

It even goes further to eliminate the proxy requirement for any app in my system. This way all those that behave crazy even with proxies can now behave!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting your browser with the proxychains command. You can configure proxychains to use pretty much any proxy and have any application run with it.

Here is a link to a short How-to:
[Proxychains How-to](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/howto.html)

Comment: didn't quite come right with this one. it started bombing out so maybe it was the proxychains setup